# Plotting formatted text

Tags: r

I need to generate a formatted string that is included on plots that indicates the median, interquartile range, and the number of observations this is based on. Here's what I'm trying...

```
plot(x=runif(4, 0,100), y=1:4, yaxt="n", ylab="", xlim=c(0,100))

m <- "2.3~x~10^6"
l <- "1.2~x~10^6"
u <- "4.5~x~10^6"
n <- 50
my_string <- paste0(m, "~(", l, "~-~", u, ")~plain(,)", "~N==~", n, "~)")
text(x=50, y=2.5, parse(text=my_string))
```

This is generating the following error...

```
Error in parse(text = my_string) : <text>:1:54: unexpected ')'
1: 2.3~x~10^6~(1.2~x~10^6~-~4.5~x~10^6)~plain(,)~N==~50~)
```

If I do

```
plot(x=runif(4, 0,100), y=1:4, yaxt="n", ylab="", xlim=c(0,100))

m <- "2.3~x~10^6"
l <- "1.2~x~10^6"
u <- "4.5~x~10^6"
n <- 50
my_string <- paste0(m, "~(", l, "~-~", u, ")")
text(x=50, y=2.5, parse(text=my_string))
```

I get the formatting I'm after with the exponent raised, but I don't have the N included. As an aside it seems to throw in additional spaces that ideally wouldn't be there.

Any suggestions to get the first code block working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt has a rogue `~)` at the end. This should work

```
my_string <- paste0(m, "~(", l, "~-~", u, ")~plain(',')", "~N==~", n)
text(x=50, y=2.5, parse(text=my_string))
```

Comment: Thanks! But why would it care about that if the parenthesis was in quotes? Also, any thoughts on the extra spacing around the comma?

Comment: Because you are `parse()`-ing the string. This means the expression needs to be valid R code. In my answer i've quoted the comma so it appears. Otherwise it's like you're passing two missing parameters to `plain()`. Again, `parse()` turns everything in an expression which must be valid R code and then the `?plotmath` magic renders that R expression into a pretty display.